# Entity Framework - Left outer join on multiple columns with OR condition

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Is it possible to write lambda left join on multiple columns that would generate OR condition instead of AND?

```cs
var query = context.table1.GroupJoin(
    context.table2,
    x => new { JoinCol1 = x.CustomerCode, JoinCol2 = x.CustomerName},
    y => new { JoinCol1 = y.Code, JoinCol2 = y.Name},
    (x, y) => new { 
        firstTable = x,
        secondTable = y
    }).SelectMany(
       x => x.OrganizationAddress.DefaultIfEmpty(),
       (x, y) => {
          x.firstTable.field1,
          x.firstTable.field2,
          y.Field3,
          y.Field4
       }
    )
```

This will generate following query

```sql
    SELECT t1.filed1, t1.field2, t2.field3, t2.field4 
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.CustomerCode = table2.Code 
                     AND table1.CustomerName = table2.Name
```

I would like to get the same query but instead of AND condition I want it to be OR:

```sql
    SELECT t1.filed1, t1.field2, t2.field3, t2.field4 
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.CustomerCode = table2.Code 
                     OR table1.CustomerName = table2.Name
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: version - EF 6.2.0

Comment: EF6 or EF Core? Version?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF 6.2.0, I will add this info to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ join operators (`Join`, `GroupJoin`) support only equi-joins. All other join types have to be implemented as correlated subqueries.

For the join in question you would simply use the alternative LINQ *left outer join* pattern - correlated `SelectMany` with `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Something like this:

```
var query = context.table1.SelectMany(
    t1 => context.table2
        .Where(t2 => t1.CustomerCode == t2.Code || t1.CustomerName == t2.Name)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (t1, t2) => new
    { 
        t1.field1,
        t1.field2,
        t2.Field3,
        t3.Field4
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: In my tests (on EF Core 6.0.7), this does not produce the SQL requested by OP. Instead, it takes _all_ rows of table1 and left joins them with the filtered rows of table2. Execution-wise, on Microsoft SQL Server Developer 15.0, this _scans all of table1_ and merge joins it with the (correctly filtered) rows of table2. That does not scale.

Comment: @Timo If you look at the comments below the question, I specially asked for EF vs EF Core and version clarification. Based on OP response, the above is for EF6, not EF Core at all. These have different LINQ query to SQL translators, so unfortunately the same tricks does not always work.

Comment: @IvanStoev I was aware, and I have no test results for the requested version, but since it is much older, it is very likely to produce a result that is equal or worse.

Comment: Apologies, I stand corrected: **With a  sufficiently large data set, SQL Server will optimize the subquery, applying the outer condition to filter it appropriately.** The accepted answer is very useful indeed.